# Как сделать, чтобы при выходе из браузера не выходило с аккаунта

Tags: php

Я хочу, чтобы при закрытии браузера пользователь оставался авторизованным (на примере ВКонтакте). Как это реализовать? (Желательно чуть-чуть поточнее, а не просто слова о том, что это, к примеру, сессии ибо я неопытен в этом деле)

Comment: Набраться опыта в сессиях вам поможет чтение соответствующей документации ;) [Раз](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php#refsect1-function.session-start-parameters), [два](http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)

Comment: Вкратце: session + cookie
создаём сессию - сохраняем нужные данные в куки и уже с ними "работаем" при следующем открытии браузера.